# Converting to ARC: retained-properties to unsafe_unretained?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to convert an existing iOS4 app to ARC with XCode and have a question about the conversion preview.
Some of the retained-properties are converted to unsafe_unretained properties. Any idea why>

For example:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImageView *icon;
```

becomes

```
@property ( unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) UIImageView *icon;
```

I expected it to be a strong-property...

Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not...depends entirely on how it is being used (and you haven't provided that information)

Comment: are you sure that the icon isnt defined as "assign" in the non arc version?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I found, that this happen, when you have retain property, but you don't release it in dealloc. When added [property release] into dealloc, the converter worked as expected - used strong type of property.